# Python script to add unittest decorators to source code files

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, file-system, meta-programming

This is a simple Python script to add `@unittest.skipUnless()` decorators in a specified format above every function starting with `test_`. I want to simplify this and try and improve it. It runs extremely quickly and does the job right now, but I'm wondering if this is best practice for modifying Python files.

Do Python developers normally just search for a regex using the IDE's search function, and then modify the search results? Is it a good idea to create a script to modify files if you're going to be repeating a code snippet a lot? How could I improve this code?

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

def decorate(file): 
    ''' 
    Goes through a file and adds @unittest.skipUnless decorators \n
    arg file -- the relative path to the file from this root directory, e.g. tests/hardware/test_device
    ''' 

    if file is not str: 
        file = str(file)

    pattern = "def test_" # the pattern that defines a test function
    template = lambda x: fr'@unittest.skipUnless((not to_test or "{x}" in to_test) and "{x}" not in to_skip, "\n**SKIPPED: {x} test**\n")'

    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace = True): 
        if pattern in line: 
            if re.search(fr"{pattern}(\d\d)", line) is not None: # if there are test function numbers (e.g. test_01)
                func_name = re.search(r"def test_\d\d_(.*)\(", line).groups()[0]
            else: # if there are not test function numbers
                func_name = re.search(r"def test_(.*)\(", line).groups()[0]
            print(f'    {template(func_name)}') 
        print(line, end="")   

    print(f"\nThe file {file} has been decorated by unittest.skipUnless decorators")


# get the filepath from the command line, then run decorate() on that file
if len(sys.argv) <= 1: 
    print("\nERROR: Need one more command line argument (relative path to file)\n")
elif len(sys.argv) > 2: 
    print("\nERROR: Too many command line arguments, should only be one (relative path to file)\n")
else: 
    file_in = sys.argv[1]
    decorate(file_in)
```